# MouseLeave event not working with left click pressed

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, mouseevent, vcl

I'm doing a test VCL app with Delphi. I have an empty form with a label and i change that label value with the form `FormMouseLeave` event. It works, but if i keep the left mouse button pressed while leaving the form the event is not triggered.

I tried intercept the `WM_MOUSELEAVE` message, but looks its not triggered at all (well, i guess `FormMouseLeave` event is based on that message)

I don't need to trigger any drag drop, i just need my event when the mouse leave my form with left click pressed, how i can do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is known behavior of `WM_MOUSELEAVE` message. You can circumvent it by tracking mouse movement and when mouse leaves form bounds you can trigger event yourself.

When you have mouse button down, then your window (form) has captured the mouse and will receive `WM_MOUSEMOVE` events even when mouse is out of it's bounds. `WM_MOUSELEAVE` message is meant for tracking mouse inside your window when you don't have mouse captured.

If you assign `MouseEnter`, `MouseLeave` and `MouseMove` events to your form you can do something like following:

```
procedure TForm1.FormMouseEnter(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Label1.Caption := '';
end;

procedure TForm1.FormMouseLeave(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Label1.Caption := 'left';
end;

procedure TForm1.FormMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if not PtInRect(ClientRect, TPoint.Create(x, y)) then Label1.Caption := 'left move';
end;
```

Answer (score 4):

When the left button goes down, the VCL framework captures the mouse, if the control underneath the mouse has `csCaptureMouse` in its control style. When the mouse is captured, the `WM_MOUSELEAVE` messages are not generated until the capture is released. That happens when the left button goes up.

If you removed `csCaptureMouse` from the control underneath the mouse, then `WM_MOUSELEAVE` message would be generated as soon as the mouse left the window, because the mouse would not have been captured.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ControlStyle := ControlStyle - [csCaptureMouse];
end;
```

Of course, changing this style just to achieve this effect is surely not what you should be doing. I just point this out to show that the issue is due to an interaction between mouse capture and mouse tracking.

But mouse tracking and `WM_MOUSELEAVE` are not really what you are looking for I think. The `WM_MOUSELEAVE` is fired when you mouse over controls on your form, which is surely not what you want.

So I think that the approach outlined in Dalija's answer is actually the correct way to implement your desired behaviour in any case, irrespective of whether or not the mouse button is down.